# Issue setting default value to one(DiceRoll.Java)

Tags: java

see attached code, this is for RollDice.Java program. I've gotten everything to work to this point but unfortunately have been unable to implement one crucial piece, setting the default face value to one upon startup... any and all suggestions on how I may go about this are welcomed, thanks...SQ

Code snippet one:

```
package rolldice;

import javax.swing.*;

public class RollDice extends JApplet {
    
    public RollDice(){
        this.setContentPane(new RollDicePanel());
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Dice Demo");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setContentPane(new RollDicePanel());
        window.pack();
        
        System.out.println(window.getContentPane().getSize());
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}
```

Code snippet 2:

```
package rolldice;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RollDicePanel extends JPanel {

    private final Die onlyDie;
    
    public RollDicePanel() {
        onlyDie = new Die();
        
        JButton rollButton = new JButton("Roll");
        rollButton.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        
        rollButton.addActionListener(new RollListener());
        
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        this.add(rollButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(onlyDie, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
    }
    
    private class RollListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            onlyDie.roll();
        }
    }
}
```

Code snippet 3:

```
package rolldice;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public final class Die extends JComponent {
        
    private static final int SPOT_DIAM = 9;  
    
    private int _faceValue;    
    
    public Die() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,60));
        roll();
    }
    
    public int roll(){
    int val = (int)(6*Math.random()+1);
    setValue(val);
    return val;
    }
    
    public int getValue(){
    return _faceValue;
    }
    
    public void setValue(int spots){
    _faceValue = spots;
    repaint();
    }
    
    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int w = getWidth();  // Get height and width
        int h = getHeight();
        
        //... Change to Graphic2D for smoother spots.
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;  // See note below
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        //... Paint background
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        
        g2.drawRect(0, 0, w-1, h-1);  // Draw border
        
        switch (_faceValue) {
            case 1:
                drawSpot(g2, w/2, h/2);
                break;
            case 3:
                drawSpot(g2, w/2, h/2);
                // Fall thru to next case
            case 2:
                drawSpot(g2, w/4, h/4);
                drawSpot(g2, 3*w/4, 3*h/4);
                break;
            case 5:
                drawSpot(g2, w/2, h/2);
                // Fall thru to next case
            case 4:
                drawSpot(g2, w/4, h/4);
                drawSpot(g2, 3*w/4, 3*h/4);
                drawSpot(g2, 3*w/4, h/4);
                drawSpot(g2, w/4, 3*h/4);
                break;
            case 6:
                drawSpot(g2, w/4, h/4);
                drawSpot(g2, 3*w/4, 3*h/4);
                drawSpot(g2, 3*w/4, h/4);
                drawSpot(g2, w/4, 3*h/4);
                drawSpot(g2, w/4, h/2);
                drawSpot(g2, 3*w/4, h/2);
                break;
        }
    
    
    
}

    private void drawSpot(Graphics2D g2, int x, int y) {
      g2.fillOval(x-SPOT_DIAM/2, y-SPOT_DIAM/2, SPOT_DIAM, SPOT_DIAM);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of caling `Dice::roll` just set `_faceValue` to the intended value when defining it or in the constructor: `private int _faceValue = 1;` or `this.faceValue = 1;`

Comment: @joshmeranda, appreciate the suggestions, and have attempted such, however my die still shows a different dot(number) value than one when I start the program. any reason as to why this may be happening?

Comment: never mind, figured it out, stupid old me, lol, thanks for your help... SQ

Answer (score 0):

what you need here is to set up a default state.
I suggest editing the actionListener. You can set the faceValue to be 1.
Then add the action listener.

The listener will not do anything without user input, so it should not affect the startup. Anything you do in there will only be executed when the Listener is triggered.
Knowing this you should be able to manipulate the faceValue of your dice outside. I suggest setting it to 1 in the constructor of your dice.
Then when the program gets executed, the dice is created, set to 1 and then waits for user input.

Want to give it a try?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).